# How to use collect to compose a node allowing empty lists as results?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, map-projections, collect

Consider a graph that looks like this:

```
(node) -> (related nodes)
a1 -> [b1, b2, b3]
a2 -> [b1]
a3 -> []
```

I want to return all the nodes extended with a list of its neighbors. My current query is the following

```
MATCH (x0:A)
MATCH (x1:B )
WHERE ((x0)-[:B]->(x1))
WITH x0,collect(x1) as x2
WITH x0,x0{.*, neighbors:x2} as x3
RETURN x3 as result
```

After executing the query I get the following result:

```
╒══════════════════════════════╕
│"result"                      │
╞══════════════════════════════╡
│{"name":"a1","neighbors":[{"na│
│me":"b1"},{"name":"b2"},{"name│
│":"b3"}]}                     │
├──────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"a2","neighbors":[{"na│
│me":"b1"}]}                   │
└──────────────────────────────┘
```

but I want that the node "a3" to also appear in the result, like this:

```
╒══════════════════════════════╕
│"result"                      │
╞══════════════════════════════╡
│{"name":"a1","neighbors":[{"na│
│me":"b1"},{"name":"b2"},{"name│
│":"b3"}]}                     │
├──────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"a2","neighbors":[{"na│
│me":"b1"}]}                   │
├──────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"a3","neighbors":[]}  │
└──────────────────────────────┘
```

How should I write the query instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MATCH (x0:A)
MATCH (x1:B )
WHERE ((x0)-[:B]->(x1))
```

is equivalent to

```
MATCH (x0:A)-[:B]->(x1:B )
```

Which says "match all A and their neighbors B where A has neighbors B". AKA, B is required. To make B optional, you need to use an optional match

```
MATCH (x0:A)
OPTIONAL MATCH (x0)-[:B]->(x1:B )
```

and now the B column is allowed to be null!

Full Query (as simplified by Cybersam)

```
MATCH (x0:A)
OPTIONAL MATCH (x0)-[:B]->(x1:B)
RETURN x0{.*, neighbors:COLLECT(x1)} AS result;
```

Comment: I had tried that but with an extra "WITH"  and it didn't work. 
"MATCH (x0:A)
OPTIONAL MATCH (x0)-[:B]->(x1:B )
WITH x0,x1"
Why? Thanks!

Comment: You need a `RETURN` clause (or else the query is doing useless work, and Cypher does not allow that).

Comment: I mean the WITH clause as part of  the query, after the optional match of the answer.

Comment: @LeoRodríguez I added the full query. (a with followed by return with no extra processing might as well be done in the return as it is equivalent). Are you having trouble with that query? (and what is the error message?)

Comment: If in the full query I put a "WITH X0, X1" before the "RETURN" I get my original undesired result. I just want to understand why, in my mind that WITH should be harmless but it isn't.

Comment: @LeoRodríguez The WITH shouldn't affect the query, but you can pre-pend "PROFILE " to your query, and neo4j will show you what it is doing.

Answer (score 3):

To add to @Tezra's answer, you can greatly simplify the rest of the query:

```
MATCH (x0:A)
OPTIONAL MATCH (x0)-[:B]->(x1:B)
RETURN x0{.*, neighbors:COLLECT(x1)} AS result;
```